# How to instantiate a weak delegate without triggering "Instance will be immediately deallocated because property 'tableViewDelegate' is 'weak'"

Tags: swift, delegates, weak

I am trying to separate out my tableView's datasource into a separate delegate object. Since that delegate needs to access the tableview at some point I need a reference to the delegating object in the delegate; and since both are classes I need to avoid strong reference cycles by making the delegate `weak`

To achieve this I tried the following code.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    weak var tableViewDelegate: UITableViewDataSource?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableViewDelegate = TableViewDelegate() // throwing a warning
        tableView.dataSource = tableViewDelegate
    }
}
```

When I try to instantiate the delegate Xcode throws a warning: "Instance will be immediately deallocated because property 'tableViewDelegate' is 'weak'"

So to fix it I do the following:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    weak var tableViewDelegate: UITableViewDataSource?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let delegate = TableViewDelegate() // worried this creates a strong reference.
        self.tableViewDelegate = delegate
        tableView.dataSource = delegate
    }
}
```

Please confirm if the following is true or not: by initialising the delegate in the viewDidLoad() method I am not in danger of creating a strong reference because the variable that holds that instance is deallocated as soon as we leave the scope of that method. Or to put it another way: the only time we need to worry about a variable (which points to a class) creating a strong reference is if the variable is initialised at the class level, and hence will live on as long as the class does.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Please confirm if the following is true or not: by initialising the delegate in the viewDidLoad() method I am not in danger of creating a strong reference because the variable that holds that instance is deallocated as soon as we leave the scope of that method.

Correct. The strong reference goes away as soon as the scope in which the `let` is declared exits.

Unfortunately, that means your delegate will still be deallocated. All you have done is silence the warning.

Basically, you need to have a strong reference to the delegate *somewhere* or it will go away straight away. My feelings is that you should make the reference in `MyViewController` strong. There will be no strong reference cycle as long as your delegate does not contain a strong reference to the view controller. If you need a reference to `MyViewController` in the delegate, make that a weak one i.e. the view controller owns the delegate, not the delegate owns the view controller.

---

Response to the comment below:

> almost all the tutorials I have found have the delegate property as weak, so it seems standard practice.

Yes it is *fairly* standard practice, there are exceptions including in Cocoa. However, it is standard practice to have a weak reference to the delegate **in the delegating object**. In your case, the delegating object is thew `UITableView` not the `MyViewController`. In your first example from the Internet, the `FileImporter` is analogous to the `UITableView` in your code. In the second example, the `DetailViewController` is the delegating object.

If you think about it, your `TableViewDelegate` is being used in place of making `MyViewController` conform to the protocol. It makes absolute sense that the `MyViewController` would own the delegate.

Comment: Yes, you are right: my delegate was still deallocated. And your proposed solution makes sense to me, BUT, almost all the tutorials I have found have the delegate property as weak, so it seems standard practice. Here are two examples:1) https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/delegation-in-swift, 2) https://useyourloaf.com/blog/unwind-segues-as-an-alternative-to-delegation/   So if standard practice dictates the delegate should be weak, how do I initialise it safely, and without triggering the warning that it will be deallocated.

Comment: Consider also that it is common for the view controller itself to be the delegate and data source of the table view it contains. This doesn't create any problems because the UITableView defines its delegate and dataSource properties as weak.

Comment: @thecloud_of_unknowing You need to look at the tutorials more closely. The reference to the delegate *in the object delegating* is usually weak (there are exceptions). In your case, this is the `UITableView`. There must be at least one strong reference somewhere or it will just go away when you don't want it to.

Comment: @JeremyP Brilliant! Thank you. I was missing the fact that the Table View (not the View Controller) is the delegating object and defines its delegate as weak.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this problem:

```
    let dataSource = MyDataSource()

    lazy var viewModel : MyViewModel = {
        let viewModel = MyViewModel(dataSource: dataSource)
        return viewModel
    }()
```

and then in viewDidLoad():

```
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = dataSource
```

You can see the full demo project [here](https://github.com/stormwright/CurrencyConverter)